# How to specify parameters for expression in C#

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I'm trying to write a Sql extension method that will handle full-text search.

```
public static class StringSearchExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> SearchByWords<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string pattern)
    {

        var tokens = pattern
            .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return tokens.Aggregate(query, (current, token) =>
            current.Where(x=> 
                PgSql.Ilike(x.TextField, $"%{token}%")));
    }
}
```

Where `TextField` is the field that I need to specify from calling code.

`PgSql` is my other extension class, containing `Ilike` method, which simply applies psql's `ILike` method.

I need to pass the parameter `x=>x.Textfield` with my arguments.

Comment: What is the actual questoin? How to call this function?

Comment: By the way, are you aware of [DbFunctions.Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.like?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) and [SqlMethods.Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Linq_SqlClient_SqlMethods_Like_System_String_System_String_)? Maybe this fits your needs.

Comment: What about restriction for <T>?
```public static IQueryable<T> SearchByWords<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string pattern)
where T: ITextFieldContained```

Comment: Typically you would use 'expressions', like  `Expression<Func<T, string>>`, to be able to translate the method to equivalent SQL, but I have no idea if it will work with like-queries since it seem to expect an actual string.

Comment: @JonasH Yes, you are right, that's what i wanted to do, but, sadly, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. It ain't not pretty, and I can't guarantee that this can be converted to SQL by the engine, but it **actually does** what you are requesting.

```
public static IQueryable<T> SearchByWords<T>(
  this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, string>> expr, string pattern)
{
  var tokens = pattern
      .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  var prop = expr.Compile();
  return tokens.Aggregate(query, (current, token) =>
      current.Where(x => PgSql.Ilike(prop.Invoke(x), $"%{token}%")));
}
```

And would be called like this:

```
var byWords = tests.SearchByWords(x => x.TextField, "myTokens");
```

Comment: This code example does not differ from passing Func<T, string> instead of Expression<Func<T, string>>. In this case I have issues in my expression tree, and it does not work with my ORM.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the key part of your problem, you'll need a method to swap the parameter of one expression, with the body of another;

```cs
Expression<Func<A, C>> Apply<A, B, C>(Expression<Func<A, B>> expr1, Expression<Func<B, C>> expr2)
    => Expression.Lambda<Func<A, C>>(
        ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(
            expr2.Parameters[0],
            expr1.Body,
            expr2.Body
        ),
        expr1.Parameters[0]
    );
```

Now for an example from your question;

```cs
Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr = x => x.Textfield;
var likeArg = $"%{token}%";
Expression<Func<string, bool>> likeExpr = str => PgSql.Ilike(str, likeArg);

var filter = Apply(fieldExpr, likeExpr);
// filter should now be equivalent to;
Expression<Func<T, bool>> expected = x => PgSql.Ilike(x.Textfield, likeArg);
```

Comment: Thanks, but, can you please share an example, how to swap parameters without EF's ReplacingExpressionVisitor?

Comment: You could copy their implementation https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Query/ReplacingExpressionVisitor.cs